# Downloading Files in WebView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview

Is it possible to download files from a website in a Mac Application using WebView? If so, how?

Comment: There is no `UIWebView` on OS X, it's `WebView`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible by using the delegate method for the `UIWebViewDelegate`, called `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` ([Link to the doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)). When the user clicks on a link, check if the extension ends with, say, ".doc" (or whatever file you want to download).

Once that is done, and the file is something you should download, then `return NO` to avoid loading the file in the Webview, and take the URL and download it on a separate object.

There are multiple other threads on how to download files with iOS, I personally recommend using the external library "ASIHTTP", which [has a download to file option](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#downloading_the_response_to_a_file).

edit: Wait, by UIWebView, you mean the [iOS UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), or the [MacOSX webView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)? If it's the later, ignore my answer.

Comment: I'm afraid it's WebView. Wasted a perfectly fine answer. +1 for effort.

Comment: Sorry, I got my terms mixed up. :\